# RAR password recovery

Tags: encryption, rar

If I have the encrypted RAR file, and I also have the unencrypted file, does there exist any way to find the cipher used by AES to decrypt it?

How does RAR encrypt files, separately, or does it encrypt them all in one? (in the case of unencrypted file name)

Comment: Please keep it on topic cprogcr. This forum is about programming, not file formats (unless related to programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot find the key, that would require a brute force attack.

It encrypts the files separately, info that can be [easily found on the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/409675/is-it-possible-for-two-files-in-a-rar-to-have-different-passwords).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't find the key or backdoor.

What you need is an brute force attack or dictionary attack.

You can try [free online rar password recovery service](http://7password.com).